# конвертация символа

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

есть строка "\x3a1" как можно определить, какой символ имеется ввиду? в исходной строке конвертация выглядит так: ":1", но есть ведь и код "\x3a1", означающий символ 'Ρ'(Greek Capital Letter Rho)

Comment: Эээ.. Куда вопрос переписал? У меня уже ответ готов.

Comment: :) я понял просто в чём ошибся и у меня возник второй вопрос, как составить массив или регулярку для вычленения кодов символов для конвертации, пример из вопроса

Comment: Не надо ничего конвертировать, просто используй utf8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неправильно понимаешь. В js символы с кодами 256 и больше не пишутся через `\x`, они пишутся через `\u`, причём ровно в 4 цифры. Ну или с фигурными скобками. А твои `\x301` - это 2 символа - `\x30` и просто `1`.

```html
<p>&#x3a1;</p>
<p><script>document.write("\u03a1")</script></p>
<p><script>document.write("\x3a1")</script></p>
<p><script>document.write("\u{3a1}")</script></p>
```